# OCaml include third party libraries with Oasis

Tags: makefile, ocaml

I am a newcomer to OCaml.
I would like to include a number of libraries form another application (a directory with a bunch of cmx,cmxa,o) files. What is the best way to do this using a tool such as OASIS? I guess the include directives for the directories have to eventually show up in the Makefile, but I am not sure how to get them there without writing the Makefile from scratch. Or are thee better options? It seems that these apects of the language are not so well documented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How was the library installed? It's highly probable they were installed via findlib. You can query the available packages like,

```
ocamlfind list
```

If it haven't, you should install the third-party library with findlib, then OASIS can easily handle including the directories. To do this manually, (once findlib is installed), create a [META](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.5.2/doc/ref-html/r695.html) file with some simple details. Then run,

```
ocamlfind install <package-name> META <list of files>
```

If you've forgotten any, you can include the -add option to add more files.

Then you just need to add the [`BuildDepends:` in your `_oasis`](https://github.com/superbobry/pareto/blob/master/_oasis#L30) file and Oasis and findlib will take care of the rest.

Comment: Library was not installed via ocamlfind, unfortunately. This complicates things, unfortunately, actually there are probably 30 different .cmx files and I am not sure about their dependencies, so writing a META would be probably too much.

Comment: could you ask the library's author about adding a META file? if they are willing that really is the best solution; furthermore it'd help the library gain adoption too.

Comment: What is the library in question?